# Vision API - Symbols missing boundingBox info for async PDF document text detection

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have a setup like this:

- PDF files get uploaded to a storage bucket
- bucket/filename is published to a pub/sub topic
- messages forwarded at a fixed rate to another pub/sub topic
- `ImageAnnotatorClient.async_batch_annotate_files()` with document_text_detection feature, and input and output GCS URIs.

I've found that in the resulting json files, the boundingBox attribute is missing for the symbol-level. Checking the documentation, symbols have a boundingBox attribute.

How can I potentially enable this for the output, or work around this?

Thanks

I tested with python in the Cloud Function and from command line. Both result in "...output-n-to-m.json" files where n and m are pagenumbers. In both outputs, at the symbol-level, boundingBox is absent. Symbols only have attributes "text" and "confidence".

The gcloud command was:
`gcloud ml vision detect-text-pdf gs://[mybucket]/[pdffile] gs://[mybucket]/[output]`